# Help me identify this rotary encoder

Tags: identification, encoder, rotary

I need help identifying this 360 degree rotary encoder on my Roland SC-880 rack synthesizer. This one has become 'jumpy' and Roland claims the part is discontinued. So my only choice is to replace it. (or figure a way to open and clean it?)

This encoder has 20 detents and a push switch to select different modes. It's 17mm x 9mm at the base, and about 37mm tall.  The synth came out in 1998 and I'm told Roland used Alps Encoders. What's the best way to go about replacing or fixing this?

[image: SC880 ENCODER1]

[image: SC880 ENCODER2]

[image: SC880 ENCODER3]

[image: SC880 ENCODER4]

Comment: Have you tried filling it with contact cleaner already?

Comment: I used DeOxit over all the visible pins and on the shaft. Though I'm not sure how to get the product 'inside' since I don't really see any visible openings.

Comment: The "top" view seems to show 3 small holes.

Comment: Those holes are very small. Like the size of a pin or smaller (<1mm) The spray probably wouldn't go in..? Any way to open this encoder without busting it?

Comment: I know that you can find very small nozzles; I picked up just today a Weller flux dispenser bottle with a 10-mil dispensing needle. Take a look around to see if you can find something similar.

Comment: Opening the existing unit to clean it is going to be pretty dicey. The thing is held together with flared rivets that come up through the top pot metal cap next to the mounting collar. It may be possible to drill out these rivets and replace with some very small #2-56 hardware to reassemble the unit.

Comment: I did just try spraying the whole thing down in DeOxit again, and I have seen about 50% improvement in function! It's hard for me to tell if those "small holes" on the top and bottom side are actually leading into the encoder. The three exposed pins on the left look dirty since they are brown while the rest of the pins look silver. But it might be a different metal? How much DeOxit can I spray onto this thing? I pretty much soaked it twice...

Comment: ... and I'm curious how the wires are attached.  Are they crimp-terminated and soldered?  What's would be the connector family for the crimp terminals and the little plastic shroud?

Comment: Yes all 4 wires are soldered to the board. Would a photo of the back of the board help?

Comment: It's at a point now where if I turn the knob quickly it pretty much works. If I turn it very slow it could jump 2 to 20 values with just one click.

Comment: Do you have any idea how many ticks this encoder has per turn? That may be an important parameter to know for suggesting a replacement.

Comment: Does this module mount via the threaded collar at the base of the shaft?

Comment: It's 20 ticks (detents) per turn. Yes it mounts by the collar at the base of the shaft.

Comment: [This](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv395=33&FV=fff4001e%2Cfff80033&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) search at Digikey can get you started.  All 20 pulse-per-turn encoders.  I looked at 5 and they all had the same pinout as the ALPS.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro Yes I found two that match closely, other then the base dimensions don't fit 17x9mm of the circuit board.

Comment: @SynthGuy, ALPS doesn't make an encoder with that footprint anymore.  The technology has evolved.  You might have to panel mount, but the electrical pins should be in the same positions.  You can cut off the clips and just be extra careful that the connection to the panel is good.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro OK I ordered ACZ11BR1E-20FD1-20C from CUI and EN11-HSM1BF20 from TT Electronics. These seem the closest fit, the TT even a bit more so (7mm brushing length) and less than half the cost. But I got them both anyway. Hope it works and I don't bust my synth in the process. :)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that Roland mounted this encoder on a small modular circuit board assembly does make it possible to think about finding an replacement encoder based mostly on the shaft mount, shaft size and knob attachment. The problem may be just a bit complicated if the existing unit also has a push switch action on the shaft.

You could make a new circuit board to accommodate the mountings of the replacement encoder. It is likely that you could even find some encoders that can direct mount via the panel collar and then you could direct wire to the encoder terminals without a circuit board.

Comment: Yes, there is a push function on the encoder to access different menus on the synth. My skills are basically novice soldering so 'cleaning' this one, or finding a very close replacement are probably my only choices without paying a professional to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

As a possible replacement encoder you may want to [look at this part from ALPS](http://www.alps.com/prod/info/E/HTML/Encoder/Incremental/EC11/EC11E09244BS.html#Photo).

[image]

If you can affix this with similar panel mounting you may be able to just wire to the leads of this device without even having to use that circuit board (just extend that existing harness as needed).

This particular encoder has 18 instead of 20 detents per turn.

[Mouser carries this particular part](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ALPS/EC11E09244BS/?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduhJtRWBpN9XewNvh1r7JYBXzfynt0RvLRGBZcxdxDbsnA%3D%3D) (EC11E09244BS) in qty 1 for $3.21.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Are you sure this part is compatible? How do I know the shaft is the correct length and size for the knob? It mounts by the collar at the base of the shaft.

Comment: Yes I see. The specs of collar 7mm and combine with shaft of 20mm are correct. Plus the knob spec looks correct. So now just need to be sure this will mount by collar?

Comment: The wires would definitely reach the pins of the encoder without any problem. I wonder the purpose of the circuit board since it's only function seems to be routing the wires to the pins.

Comment: The circuit board does several things. Eliminates hand soldered wires. And it provides a clean way to terminate the connection harness as 4-wires instead of 5 as may typically be soldered to this type of switch. (Clearly the switch and the encoder share a wire in the harness - probably a GND).

Comment: My concern with your alps replacement was the 9PPR for 18 detents. I didn't know how that would affect the function. So, from digikey, I ordered ACZ11BR1E-20FD1-20C from CUI and EN11-HSM1BF20 from TT Electronics. These seem the closest fit, the TT even a bit more so (7mm brushing length) and less than half the cost. I think I should be able to solder one of these on the existing circuit board. I hope I'm on the right path, and value your help very much. Thank you!